# Documentation/ library to implement pull to show more menu options in UICollectionView/ UITableView

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uicollectionview

There is one common UI pattern which I often observe in several popular iOS apps (Like WhatsApp, Zoho Notebook), but is not discussed in Apple's documentation.

When you pull down the `UICollectionView` (or `UITableView`), more menu options will be shown.

For instance...

---

### WhatsApp

1. Pull down `UICollectionView` (or `UITableView`. Not sure what component they are using)
2. A `UITextField` for search is shown
3. Pull down again
4. Archive menu is shown

[image]

---

### Zoho Notebook

1. Pull down `UICollectionView` (I guess it is not `UITableView`, as it comes with customised grid layout)
2. Button at left (For sorting) and button at right (For changing view) are shown

[image]

---

Do you have any idea, how is these common UI pattern being implemented?

Is there any documentation/ library to implement pull to show more menu options in `UICollectionView`/ `UITableView`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They are probably just inserting a cell or showing a hidden view when the `refreshControl` is updated.

```
    refreshControl.addTarget(self, action: #selector(reloadFeed), for: UIControl.Event.valueChanged)
    collectionView.refreshControl = refreshControl
```